# How can you redirect to local page after successful login via Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

So, I've successfully logged in a user in a project via Firebase auth (Facebook). The problem I'm having is that once a user is logged in, how can you redirect them to another page of the application? I keep getting a 400 Post error, which seems like it's related to the hash that the url is being concatonated (?) onto?

I tried to use signInWithRedirect(provider) - However, this redirects them to the Facebook site.

I also tried to use both signInWithRedirect and getRedirectResult, but those also redirect back to Facebook site to complete login.

Currently, I'm using an onAuthStateChanged, which I've included the code for below: (Note, I've also used window.location = 'home.html', window.location.href = 'home.html', window.location('home.html'), url('home.html'), and any other combinations I thought might work.

```
      // ------ //

        document.getElementById('facebook').onclick = function() {

          var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();


        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
          // This gives you a Facebook Access Token. You can use it to access the Facebook API.
          var token = result.credential.accessToken;
          // The signed-in user info.
          var user = result.user;
          // ...
        }).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          // The email of the user's account used.
          var email = error.email;
          // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
          var credential = error.credential;
          // ...
        });

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if(user) {
          window.location = url('latest.html'); //After successful login, user will be redirected to Latest page
        }
        });//end of onAuthStateChanged

        }; //end of Facebook auth


        // ------- //


  }; //end of window.onload function
```

Comment: The code you shared doesn't do any `POST` call, so it shouldn't be throwing that error. Can you show the complete error message, and any stack trace that might be showing for it? Also note that it's more likely we can help, if you show the [minimal, standalone code with which anyone can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Frank. I've updated the code in the question. Please also note that I've used the const firebaseConfg object as well as the firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); in a main.js file.

Comment: The error is: www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=AIzaSyALhPYEX3ZGftrH25ZSa0rczkxuULfWjvE:1 POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=AIzaSyALhPYEX3ZGftrH25ZSa0rczkxuULfWjvE 400

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that the error has to do with the `onAuthStateChanged` or the redirect. Where exactly does the error come from?